# How to give 5dp linespace to TextView programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I want to change the linespace of a TextView programatically. I searched and I found `setLineSpacing`. The problem is this, it gets two parameters, I've tried so many values but I couldn't get the result I wanted. I just need to give the TextView 5dp linespace, what should I put in the method to give it 5 dp linespace?

Answer (score 28):

Why can't you use `setLineSpacing?`
That is exactly what I'd use.

Based on the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLineSpacing(float,%20float)):

> public void setLineSpacing (float add, float mult)
>
> Each line will have its height multiplied by mult and have add added to it.

So here's what you may choose to do:

```
myTextView.setLineSpacing(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5.0f,  getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 1.0f);
```

Or you can modify the XML Layout of `android:lineSpacingExtra`. (See [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingExtra).)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If pulling a dimen resource:

```
setLineSpacing(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.dp5), 1.0f)
```